# WKWebView not in Xcode

Tags: xcode, wkwebview

I need to implement the WKWebview for my ios app with Xcode. However i have error when using it "undeclared type 'WKWebview'". Do i missing anything important.

I'm using the latest Xcode7 download from App Store.

Comment: We'll need to see a bit of code.

Answer (score 131):

If you are using swift, first import the WebKit module in any files you're using web kit API:

```
import WebKit
```

Then you can use the web view:

```
let webView = WKWebView()
```

Answer (score 67):

you need to import webkit in file

```
import WebKit
```

Answer (score 32):

You should import the header `#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>`

and add `WebKit.framework` in Build Phases if you're using objective-c.

Answer (score 19):

Swift 5:

```
import WebKit
```

**And** add `WebKit.framework` in Frameworks section under General project settings

Answer (score 13):

still dealing with Objective-C?

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
```